# A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Помогите разобраться с мистическим поведением.
Имеется сущность

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "line")
public class Line extends BaseCrudEntity<Line, Long> { 
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Property> properties; 
...

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "property")
public class Property extends BaseCrudEntity<Property, Long> {
...

@Repository("LineRepository") public interface LineRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Line, Long> {

@Service public class LineCrudServiceImpl {  
@Autowired  LineRepository lineRepository;  
public Line save(Line entity) {
        return lineRepository.save(entity);  
}
```

Когда я в контроллере получаю обновлённую Line с изменёнными Properties, или просто такую же, то получаю ошибку

```
 Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.HibernateExcep
tion: A collection with cascade="all-delete-orphan" was no longer referenced by the owning entity instance: by.legan.web.manager_sorc.domain.data.monitoring.Line.proper
ties]
```

Вот так я получаю в контроллере обновлённую сущность Line,
BaseCrudController является базовым, наследуюсь и не меняю функционал

```
public  abstract class BaseCrudController<T extends BaseCrudEntity, K extends Serializable>
@PostMapping
public T save(@Valid @RequestBody T entity) {
    return this.getService().save(entity);
}
....
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/rest/line")
public class LineRestApiCrudController extends BaseCrudController<Line, Long> {
....
```

я разворачиваю war файл на сервере TomCat 9.0.0 и локально при разработке я делаю тоже самое, но эффект разный. 
Локально нет ни каких ошибок как бы я не менял структуру Line всё корректно,  а на сервере в продакшене стабильно эта ошибке при сохранении сущности.

https://youtu.be/O_Cl-eZC4gc

Выгрузил вес проект в git/repo временный (удалил только пароли к базе)
https://legan.by/gitea/VPKiTS/HibernateErrorTempGitRepo

---

Проблема вроди как решилась, еще буду тестировать дольше, после добавления в контроллере запроса сущности перед её сохранением.

```
@PostMapping
public T save(@Valid @RequestBody T entity) {
    if (Objects.nonNull(entity.getId())) get((K) entity.getId()); // Вот эта строка
    return this.getService().save(entity);
}
```

Не знаю почему, но работает только так ....... , может потому что коллекция fetch=FetchType.LAZY

Comment: А `Property` - это сущность? Аннотации `@Entity` стоят над `Line` и `Property`?

Comment: да конешно,  и всё работает локально, при одинаковых версиях всего

Comment: а чем отличается конфиг прода от локального? (что имеет отношение к бд)

Comment: в том то и дело что ни в чём, MySQL база открыта на ружу (для удобства разработки) и прод и локальная копия используют одну базу. Отличия есть я вспомнил на прод OpenJDK , локально Oracle но версии одинаковые

Comment: добавил в шапку, установил везде OpenJDK одинаковой версии, ситуация не изменилась, при разработке всё хорошо, в проде падает по этой дурацкой ошибке.

Comment: Добавте еще пжл код классов `Line` и `Property`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95964/discussion-between-not-a-programmer-and-andrey-lehan).